# Mock Action functions in Jest test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, reactjs-flux, jestjs

How would one go about calling a function from an imported action module? Here is my component

```
class Task extends Component {
 handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Actions.returnTask(this.props.id);
 }
 render() {...}
}
```

and tests that look like this:

```
jest.dontMock('./Task');
jest.dontMock('./Actions');

describe('Tasks', function() {
 let renderedComponent;
 let mockReturnTask;
 let TaskActions;
 beforeEach(function() {
  renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
   <Task task={testTask} key={1} />
    );
   Actions = require('./Actions');
   mockReturnTask = jest.genMockFn();
   Actions.returnTask = mockReturnTask;
  });
  it('should call a returnTask action on Actions', function() {
   renderedComponent.handleClick(event);
   expect(mockReturnTask).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

When running my test it tells me that the function was not called. If I do `expect(Actions.returnTask).toBeCalled();` I get an error message that `toBeCalledWith() should be used on a mock function` error. How do I mock a function on the external Actions and check that it is called in my tests? I feel like my method above should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't include the require of `Task` but I'm pretty sure of what happened here. Jest users must be aware of what `require` they do, and when.

Chronologically:

1. jest is set to never mock `Actions` and `Task`
2. `Task` component is required, jest requires it for real
3. `Actions` is required because it is required in the `Task` component. jest requires it for real.
4. `Task` component is instantiated
5. `Actions.returnTask` is monkey-patched but **it's not the function the component is bind with**, it's a new function who exist only in the test.

To make your component using a jest mocked function, you have to require and monkey-patch `Actions` **before** requiring `Tasks`

Be aware that you don't have to unmocked `Actions` if you mock a function of Actions right after. It's exactly what the jest auto-mocking *killing feature* is made for : remove `jest.dontMock('./Actions');` and all references to your `Actions` module. The test should be working.